# Is it possible to identify the source of a protein hydrolysate

Tags: chemical-biology, identification, structural-biology

I have a powder which only declares to be "Protein Hydrolysate"
Meaning that the all the protein has been broken down.

We've tried to identify the source of the powder with DNA research. But no usable DNA (parts) where found.

Is there a way to identify the source of this powder? (ie. chicken, pork, cow, shark, dolphins or unicorns)

For clarification, we failed to find any DNA in the powder. so we're looking for alternative ways to analyse it.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question: Protein != DNA

Comment: DNA research? Unless there's a total misconception in this question it's very ambiguous.

Comment: I've added a clarification in the question. DNA is protein, but since we're talking about a hydrolysate all protein and therefor DNA is broken down to it's amino acids (or small pieces of protein). Meaning that DNA analysis gives zero result. So we're looking for alternative methods to analyse the powder

Comment: Proteins are made of 22 common types of natural aminoacids. The combination of those results in a sea of **different** proteins. Furthermore, you can have a protein with for example 300 cysteines, 250 glycines and 50 tryptophans, while another one contains 300 glycines, 250 tryptophans and 50 cysteines. They will vary very very very deeply.

Answer (score 3):

1. DNA is **not** a protein, as @MARamezani states. See http://www.answers.com/Q/Is_DNA_a_protein.
2. There is a prevalence (or lack) of some amino acids in certain sources. For example, maize ("corn" in America) is deficient in tryptophan and lysine, so if your sample is short on those two, it is *more likely* that it is from corn. A list of some foods and amino acid content is at http://www.ljhs.sandi.net/faculty/aquesnell/Biology%20Notes/Chapter%204/4.8-4.13/Essential%20Amino%20Acids.pdf [there appear to be some errors, though]. According to that source, yeast may be deficient in phenylalanine, so that is another indicator.

You would need an analysis of the relative abundance of each amino acid, some reference showing their abundance in various sources, *and additional analysis to calculate relative abundances in a **mixture**, e.g. corn supplemented with yeast hydrolyzate.*